# Errors in $_POST variables in PHP file and array

Tags: php, forms

The php file works correctly when I hard code the values into it.  When I do a post from the html form I can see the variables correctly so I know they are passing to the php file.  However, I am getting errors in the script when I use the $_POST of the values into the places where the hard coded values work.

Here is the hard coded values that work:

```
$accountID = "XXXXXXXX";
$secretKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$mode = "TEST";

$payment = new BluePay(
    $accountID,
    $secretKey,
    $mode,
);

$payment->setCustomerInformation(array(
    'firstName' => 'Bob', 
    'lastName' => 'Tester', 
    'addr1' => '1234 Test St.', 
    'addr2' => 'Apt #500', 
    'city' => 'Testville', 
    'state' => 'IL', 
    'zip' =>'54321', 
    'country' => 'USA', 
    'phone' => '1231231234', 
    'email' => 'test@bluepay.com' 
));
```

Here is the altered php form with the $_POST.  I am getting ; errors in it.  Am I calling the $_POST correctly in the setup and arrays?  Currently getting NAME error which is coming back from the processor for the name not passing through.

```
<?php

include('BluePay.php');

$payment = new BluePay(
    $_POST['accountID'], 
    $_POST['secretKey'],
    $_POST['mode']
);

$arrayVar = array(
        $firstName => $_POST['firstName'],
        $lastName => $_POST['lastName'],
        $addr1 => $_POST['addr1'],
        $addr2 => $_POST['addr2'],
        $city => $_POST['city'],
        $state => $_POST['state'],
        $zip => $_POST['zip'],
        $country => $_POST['country'],
        $phone => $_POST['phone'],
        $email => $_POST['email']
    );

$payment->setCustomerInformation($arrayVar);

$payment->setCCInformation(array(
    'cardNumber' => '4111111111111111', // Card Number: 4111111111111111
    'cardExpire' => '1217', // Card Expire: 12/15
    'cvv2' => '123' // Card CVV2: 123
));

/* $arrayVar2 = array(
    $cardNumber => $_POST['cardNumber'],
    $cardExpire => $_POST['cardExpire'], 
    $cvv2 => $_POST['cvv2'] 
);

$payment->setCCInformation($arrayVar2); */

$payment->sale('3.00'); // Sale Amount: $3.00 
//$payment['sale'] => $_POST['sale'];

 // Makes the API request with BluePay
$payment->process();

// Reads the response from BluePay
if($payment->isSuccessfulResponse()){
    echo 
    'Transaction Status: '. $payment->getStatus() . "\n" .
    'Transaction Message: '. $payment->getMessage() . "\n" .
    'Transaction ID: '. $payment->getTransID() . "\n" .
    'AVS Response: ' . $payment->getAVSResponse() . "\n" .
    'CVS Response: ' . $payment->getCVV2Response() . "\n" .
    'Masked Account: ' . $payment->getMaskedAccount() . "\n" .
    'Card Type: ' . $payment->getCardType() . "\n" .
    'Authorization Code: ' . $payment->getAuthCode() . "\n";
} else{
    echo $payment->getMessage() . "\n";
}
?>
```

Here is the html form

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="ccpost.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="accountID" value="XXXXXXXXXX" />
<input type="hidden" name="secretKey" value="XXXXXXXXXXX />
<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="TEST" />
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName"><br>
Address 1: <input type="text" name="addr1"><br>
Address 2: <input type="text" name="addr2"><br>
City: <input type="text" name="city"><br>
State: <input type="text" name="state"><br>
Zip Code: <input type="text" name="zip"><br>
Country: <input type="text" name="country"><br>
Phone: <input type="text" name="phone"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
Card Number: <input type="text" name="cardNumber"><br>
Card Expire: <input type="text" name="cardExpire"><br>
Cvv: <input type="text" name="cvv2"><br>
Sale: <input type="text" name="sale"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please paste html form code as well?

Comment: You are not using the array function correctly. Instead of array($firstName=$_POST['fistName'];) it should be array( $firstName => $_POST['firstName'], $lastName => $_POST['lastName'])

Comment: so a comma between them?

Comment: How did I miss this? You're not using commas. Don't use ; between elements, use , .

Comment: I updated it with the commas.  However I am PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')'  in the payment area.

Comment: @LZad Please also add complete ccpost.php file where issue is coming

Comment: I pasted all of it.  I still have some of the hard coded values in it

Answer (score 0):

There seems an error in your PHP, below is the updated:

```
$payment = new BluePay(
    $_POST['accountID'], // you don't need to  $accountID = $_POST['accountID']
    $_POST['secretKey'],
    $_POST['mode']
);

$arrayVar = array(
        $firstName => $_POST['firstName'],
        $lastName => $_POST['lastName'],
        $addr1 => $_POST['addr1'],
        $addr2 => $_POST['addr2'],
        $city => $_POST['city'],
        $state => $_POST['state'],
        $zip => $_POST['zip'],
        $country => $_POST['country'],
        $phone => $_POST['phone'],
        $email => $_POST['email']
    );

$payment->setCustomerInformation($arrayVar);
```

Comment: PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' after the mode line.  It was the no comma I placed after the mode.

Comment: I tried to repeat some of the items you did on the variable.  $payment->sale('3.00'); // Sale Amount: $3.00 
// $payment => $_POST['sale'];  The first one works when I hard code it.  What is wrong when I apply the $_POST to it

Comment: `$payment => $_POST['sale']`, this is invalid. I believe, you want something like `$payment['sale'] => $_POST['sale']`.. ?

Comment: That also generates an error in the => in the sales.  When I hard code that area the name is not working correct in the arrayVar.  I don't see where or how.  But it I hardcode that area with the one above it work.